# How to change localhost API URL when deployed to Heroku?

Tags: reactjs, heroku, localhost, web-deployment, server-side

I've deployed an server-side rendering React app (bundled without CRA):

- it has an express server for server-side rendering (listens to port 3000 or `process.env.PORT`)
- it has an express server for the API that serves the frontend (listens to port 8080 or `process.env.PORT`)

On localhost, the frontend makes a request to `http://localhost:8080/api` to get the data, which works perfectly.

From my understanding, when the app is in production, the base API URL should be the app's URL (eg. https://myapp.herokuapp.com) instead of `http://localhost:8080`, so I added this change in my code:

- if the app is in dev, the frontend calls `http://localhost:8080/api`
- if the app is in prod, the frontend calls `https://myapp.herokuapp.com/api`(I added `https://myapp.herokuapp.com/`as a config var in Heroku)

However, it doesn't work. My app is deployed successfully to Heroku and the SSR renders correctly, but the API call fails. (I also tried `https://myapp.herokuapp.com/api:3000` which fails)

What should be the API URL to call a local server when the app is in production?

thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Well, as far as I know Heroku doesn't allow multiple ports and you will not be able to open 3000 for web and 8080 for api.

You can serve both on the same port and route `/api` to the api.

I have worked on a project that uses similar approach and below is the code:

```
app.use('/api', router); // every api route is in the router
app.use(express.static(staticDir));
```

It is also deployed to heroku.

full repo if you wish to take a look - https://github.com/berkeli/breteau-dashboard/blob/main/server/utils/createServer.js